# How to take the snapshot of device if device is not rooted?

Tags: android

Hi i saw the code for taking snapshot of android device if the device is rooted. How i can take the snapshot if the device is not rooted programatically

Comment: what do u mean by rooted and not rooted?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [this sample project](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/source/browse/), it does what you need (browse to *src* and find *ScreenshotDemo.java*)

Answer (score 0):

The following App allows you to to take screenshots without root access.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfullnoroot&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I had searched lot about this. Without root u can try ASL it works depending on phones  ie; if u r lucky . All other apps require root permission for screenshot.